# help installing nmap 6.40 on 12.04

Tags: 12.04, nmap

im trying to install

i tried following the instructions in the nmap site by doing this:

```
bzip2 -cd nmap-6.40.tar.bz2 | tar xvf -
cd nmap-6.40
./configure
make
su root
make install
```

and it all works well untill i type in make and i seem to get something that is an error

```
/nmap-6.40$ make
Compiling liblua
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua'
make[1]: `liblua.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua'
Compiling liblinear
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblinear'
make[1]: `liblinear.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblinear'
Compiling libpcap
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcap'
VER=`cat ./VERSION`; \
    MAJOR_VER=`sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/' ./VERSION`; \
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libpcap.so.$MAJOR_VER  \
        -o libpcap.so.$VER pcap-linux.o pcap-usb-linux.o pcap-can-linux.o pcap-netfilter-linux.o fad-getad.o pcap.o inet.o gencode.o optimize.o nametoaddr.o etherent.o savefile.o sf-pcap.o sf-pcap-ng.o pcap-common.o bpf_image.o bpf_dump.o  scanner.o grammar.o bpf_filter.o version.o   
/usr/bin/ld: cannot open output file libpcap.so.1.2.1: Permission denied
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [libpcap.so] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcap'
make: *** [pcap_build] Error 2
qayin@kraken-PC:~/nmap-6.40$ sudo make
Compiling liblua
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua'
make[1]: `liblua.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua'
Compiling liblinear
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblinear'
make[1]: `liblinear.a' is up to date.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblinear'
Compiling libpcap
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcap'
VER=`cat ./VERSION`; \
    MAJOR_VER=`sed 's/\([0-9][0-9]*\)\..*/\1/' ./VERSION`; \
    gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,libpcap.so.$MAJOR_VER  \
        -o libpcap.so.$VER pcap-linux.o pcap-usb-linux.o pcap-can-linux.o pcap-netfilter-linux.o fad-getad.o pcap.o inet.o gencode.o optimize.o nametoaddr.o etherent.o savefile.o sf-pcap.o sf-pcap-ng.o pcap-common.o bpf_image.o bpf_dump.o  scanner.o grammar.o bpf_filter.o version.o   
./config.status --file=pcap-config.tmp:./pcap-config.in
config.status: creating pcap-config.tmp
mv pcap-config.tmp pcap-config
chmod a+x pcap-config
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcap'
Compiling libpcre
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcre'
make  all-am
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcre'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcre'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libpcre'
Compiling libdnet
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped'
Making all in include
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include'
make  all-recursive
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include'
Making all in dnet
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include/dnet'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include/dnet'
make[4]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include'
make[4]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/include'
Making all in src
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/src'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped/src'
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all-am'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/libdnet-stripped'
Compiling libnbase
cd nbase && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nbase'
make[1]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nbase'
Compiling libnsock
cd nsock/src && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nsock/src'
cd ../../nbase && make
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nbase'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nbase'
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nsock/src'
cd ncat && make
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/ncat'
Compiling liblua
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua'
make[2]: `liblua.a' is up to date.
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua'
Compiling libnsock
cd ../nsock/src && make
make[2]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nsock/src'
cd ../../nbase && make
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nbase'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nbase'
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/nsock/src'
gcc -o test/addrset -g -O2 -Wall -L../libpcap  test/addrset.o ncat_core.o sys_wrap.o util.o ncat_lua.o -ldl -ldl  ../nsock/src/libnsock.a ../nbase/libnbase.a  -lpcap ./../liblua/liblua.a -lm
./../liblua/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_sym':
/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua/loadlib.c:142: undefined reference to `dlsym'
./../liblua/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_load':
/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua/loadlib.c:135: undefined reference to `dlopen'
./../liblua/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_sym':
/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua/loadlib.c:143: undefined reference to `dlerror'
./../liblua/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_load':
/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua/loadlib.c:136: undefined reference to `dlerror'
./../liblua/liblua.a(loadlib.o): In function `ll_unloadlib':
/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/liblua/loadlib.c:130: undefined reference to `dlclose'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [test/addrset] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/qayin/nmap-6.40/ncat'
make: *** [ncat_build] Error 2
```

anyhow i try to continue and `su root` and i get authentication failure for some reason,  so i did `sudo su` instead, and then it says im root
but `make install` does not work, giving me the replay:
`make: *** No rule to make target`libnetutil/libnetutil.a', needed by `nmap  Stop.`

ty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't tried buidling this version of nmap, but based on my previous experience there is an issue with the Makefile for the ncat subcomponent not respecting the gcc library link-order requirements with respect to libdl

If you only need nmap itself, then the easiest workaround is simply to configure the build without the ncat component i.e. run

```
./configure --without-ncat
```

and then perform the `make` and `make install` steps again. Since you used `sudo` for the make step last time you will likely need to do so again, since any object files will have been created with root ownership - however it would be preferable to fix the original ownership / permissions issue.

If you do need to build the ncat component, then you will probably have to edit the corresponding Makefile, as described [here on ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2164741&p=12742944#post12742944)

You can read more about library link-order in [the gcc documentation](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html) or see for example [Linker order - GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409470) on stackoverflow

Comment: Yes, the fix is in SVN, and involves putting `-ldl` later in the `LIBS`. http://seclists.org/nmap-dev/2013/q3/262

Comment: im still stuck for some reason, when i `make` i still get a long error.. not sure what to do - what would be my best option to remove EVERYTHING ive done so far and start off fresh?

Comment: It would probably be simplest to delete the whole ncat directory and unpack a fresh copy of the source tarball, then `configure --without-ncat` or `configure --with-ncat=no` - if that doesn't work then edit your post to indicate the exact error(s) you are getting when you run the `make` command

Comment: ok that makes sense, ill do that in a few mins and see what i get

Comment: not sure what to make of this but sadly `find ./ ncat` says `no such file or directory` - im so confused

Comment: Are you sure you unpacked the tarball correctly? I have just downloaded nmap-6.40.tar.bz2 from http://nmap.org and it configured and built successfully on my 12.04.3 laptop using `./configure --with-ncat=no --prefix=/usr/local` (the `--prefix` part is optional - I like to sandbox any non-standard installations in `/usr/local/`)

Answer (score 1):

Just download the rpm and run the following script:

```
alien nmap-6.47-1.x86_64.rpm
```

then you will have the deb file to install via

```
dpkg -i nmap_6.47-2_amd64.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo apt-get update
it updates
$ sudo apt-get install nmap
install nmap
$ nmap --version 
tells you the version of nmap
```